# How do you call an external program in Ada?

Tags: ada, gnat

How do you call an external command (as if I'd typed it at the Unix shell or Windows command prompt) from within Ada program text?

I'd prefer a non-gnat-specific solution, but I'll post what I found on my own as an initial answer anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also use `system`. Supported on e.g.

- Linux ([see here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html))
- Windows ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/system-wsystem?view=vs-2019))

Note that errors are written to standard error.

**main.adb**

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Interfaces.C;

procedure Main is

   package C renames Interfaces.C;
   use type C.int;
   
   function system (command : C.char_array) return C.int
     with Import, Convention => C;

   command : aliased constant C.char_array :=
     C.To_C ("mv README.md README.txt");

   result : C.int;

begin
   result := system (command);
   if result = 0 then
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("OK");
   else
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line ("Failed");
   end if;
end Main;
```

Comment: How would you do this for a non-blocking system call? I was surprised to find GNAT.OS_Lib.Spawn does not call system under the hood. It calls '__gnat_portable_spawn', and Non_Blocking_Spawn does similarly; again, this is because I am looking for something to replace the GNAT runtime specific '__gnat_portable_no_block_spawn', so that the code will compile using any Ada compiler.

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn If you do not want to use the GNAT specific abstractions in `OS_Lib`, then I'm afraid you'll have to use the OS specific C system calls, most likely those those used by `Spawn` (see e.g. [`adaint.c`](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/ada/adaint.c;h=c44d193233272c8b1cd43a54a69e23da436eb58f;hb=HEAD#l2699)). Ada itself (i.e. the standard library) doesn't know the concept of processes.

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn For the interaction with POSIX compatible OS'es (e.g. for starting processes, etc.), there was, at some point in time, a POSIX Ada language interface available (see [ISO/IEC 14519:2001](https://www.iso.org/standard/34354.html) and [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Platform/POSIX) Wiki page) along with a (compiler independent) implementation called [Florist](https://github.com/Blady-Com/florist) (see `posix-process_primitives.ads` for the process primitives). This library, however, seems somewhat deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

```pascal
with GNAT.OS_Lib;
procedure main is
   Exit_Code : Integer;
begin
   Exit_Code := GNAT.OS_Lib.Spawn (Program_Name => "mv", Args => (new String'("README.md"), new String'("README.txt")));
   if Exit_Code /= 0 then
      raise Program_Error with "Exit code:" & Exit_Code'Image;
   end if;
end main;
```

Change 'mv' to 'move' if you are on windows.

See [the GNAT.OS_Lib documentation](https://www.radford.edu/%7Enokie/classes/320/std_lib_html/gnat-os_lib.html) to extend this for non-blocking and/or capturing the stdout/stderr.

Answer (score 1):

We have a nice Process API with asynchronous notifications. Take a look at [an example](https://github.com/AdaCore/ada_language_server/blob/master/testsuite/spawn/spawn_test.adb). It work on Linux, Windows and Mac OS X. There is optional integration with Glib event loop.

```
   Args : Spawn.String_Vectors.UTF_8_String_Vector;
   L    : aliased Listeners.Listener;
begin
   Args.Append ("Hello World");
   P.Set_Program ("/bin/echo");
   P.Set_Arguments (Args);
   P.Set_Working_Directory ("/tmp");
   P.Set_Listener (L'Unchecked_Access);
   P.Start;
```

Comment: Why is Spawn.String_Vectors.UTF_8_String_Vector defined? Is there a reason why the Ada.Strings one can't be used?

Comment: @ATL_DEV Package `Ada.Strings` doesn't provide any string vector type nor string type. Standard String type is able to contain only characters from Latin_1 character set. Idea to represent bytes needed to UTF-8 encoding as Character is ugly and works bad in practice. Represent argument list as a single string stops working when you need to pass spaces, quotes, backslashes, because all this is platform dependent. So we need explicit vector of Unicode strings here. Probably we will switch to [VSS Strings](https://github.com/AdaCore/VSS/) at some time.

Comment: Good point. Coupling the UTF_8_String_Vector to Spawn is a bit of an oversight.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comments regarding the Florist library (see [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62659296)), I added another example (just for reference and info, not as a serious answer to the original question). Unfortunately, the version of Florist I refer to in the comments does not compile on recent versions of GNAT (e.g. GNAT CE 2020). This version of the library seems to have become somewhat dependent on GNAT's internals which have been modified slightly (so the library is not as compiler independent anymore as originally intended). Nonetheless, for completeness, if you would be able to compile it (using either an older version of GNAT or by repairing the source code), then the example below would spawn a child process without blocking and wait for it to finish.

**main.adb**

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with POSIX;       use POSIX;

with POSIX.Process_Primitives;
with POSIX.Process_Identification;

procedure Main is
   
   package PP renames POSIX.Process_Primitives;
   package PI renames POSIX.Process_Identification;
   
   Filename : constant POSIX_String := "sleep";
   Args     : POSIX_String_List;  
   
   PID : PI.Process_ID;
   PT  : PP.Process_Template;   
   PS  : PP.Termination_Status;
   
begin
   Append (Args, Filename);   --  argv[0]
   Append (Args, "5");        --  argv[1]

   PP.Open_Template (PT);
   
   PP.Start_Process_Search
     (Child    => PID,
      Filename => Filename,
      Template => PT,
      Arg_List => Args);

   loop
      Put_Line ("Waiting...");
      
      PP.Wait_For_Child_Process
        (Status => PS,
         Child  => PID,
         Block  => False);
      
      exit when PP.Status_Available (PS);
      delay 1.0;
   end loop;
   
   Put_Line ("The child terminated with status code: "
               & PP.Exit_Status_Of (PS)'Image);
   
   PP.Close_Template (PT);   
end Main;
```

**output**

```
$./obj/main
Waiting...
Waiting...
Waiting...
Waiting...
Waiting...
Waiting...
The child terminated with status code:  0
```