# How can I start a process and convert its PID to/from an integer?

Tags: ada

I'm writing a process manager in Ada, for Linux. I'm using `GNAT.OS_Lib` to spawn processes:

```
Pid := GNAT.OS_Lib.Non_Blocking_Spawn(
    Program_Name => Program,
    Args => Arguments
);
```

This gets me back the PID as a `Process_Id`, an `OS_Lib` private type. I would like to be able to store this PID in a file *as an integer*, for compatibility with other, non-Ada code, and then re-load it later from that file and use it from within Ada to kill the process, check its status, etc.

`OS_Lib` provides a `Pid_To_Integer` function, but not the inverse.

Perhaps I need a different library? As far as I can tell, there are no current Ada POSIX libraries. Should I write one myself? I only need support for like three POSIX calls. I'm open to all suggestions.

Comment: Have you looked at [Florist](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnat-florist/)?

Comment: @JeffreyR.Carter I found a reference to it in [another SE answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62682994/815612) that said it was deprecated and doesn't work with modern Ada/GNAT, is that not the case?

Comment: The repository I referenced is newer than the post you referenced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chasing through the RTS for the definition, `g-os_lib.ads` says

```ada
with System.OS_Lib;

package GNAT.OS_Lib renames System.OS_Lib;
```

and at the bottom of `s-os_lib.ads` we find

```ada
type Process_Id is new Integer;
```

so I’d go for `Ada.Unchecked_Conversion`.

Comment: So this is basically the equivalent of a C-style cast, and works even when the type is private?

Comment: Yes (just tested to confirm, macOS). You get a warning at compile time if the objects to be converted aren’t the same size.

Comment: Thanks! In the end I just rolled my own bindings to the stuff I needed (this is a learning project, not production code). I'll defer to your experience and accept this answer on the assumption that this is the better way to do it for a general use case.

Answer (score 3):

In the end, I wrote my own implementation. Here is an example of how to run `execv` and `fork` in Ada.

`main.adb`

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with Interfaces.C.Strings;

procedure Main is
    subtype C_String is Interfaces.C.Strings.chars_ptr;
    Null_String: C_String := Interfaces.C.Strings.Null_Ptr;

    function As_C_String(s: String) return C_String renames Interfaces.C.Strings.New_String;

    type Argument_List is Array(1..2) of C_String;

    function Execute(Program: C_String; Arguments: Argument_List) return Integer
        with Import => True, Convention => C, External_Name => "execv";
    function Fork return Integer
        with Import => True, Convention => C, External_Name => "fork";

    Program: C_String := As_C_String("/bin/sh");
    Args: Argument_List := (Program, Null_String);

    N : Integer;
    Pid: Integer;
begin
    Pid := Fork;
    if Pid = 0
    then
        N := Execute(Program, Args);
    else
        Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(Pid'Image);
    end if;
end Main;
```

`main.gpr`

```
project Main is

   for Languages use ("ada");

   for Source_Dirs use (".");
   for Main use ("main.adb");
   for Object_Dir use "obj";
   for Exec_Dir use ".";

end Main;
```

Compiling with `gprbuild` and it works fine. Run `main` and you should see an integer in the console, run `ps ux` and you should see an instance of `sh` running with that PID.